# Is it unhealthy to never be sick?

Tags: common-cold, influenza

According to some websites, such as [this one](https://holisticspring.com/archives/16358) and [this one](https://advancednaturopathic.com/never-getting-sick-isnt-necessarily-healthy/), it is unhealthy when you are never sick. It would be better if you are sick once or twice a year. The reason they state is that when you never get sick, pathogens can come inside your body and your immune system might be too weak to give the proper response, which can have long term negative consequences.

I have searched some other websites. [This one](https://www.today.com/today/amp/tdna2761) says that it is unknown why some people never get sick. [Another website](https://www.eatthis.com/news-simple-ways-to-never-get-sick/) says that never being sick is a good thing.

So I have found a lot of contradictory statements. However, none of them seems to be from an authoritative source. So should we be sick every year?

Comment: The reason you don't feel sick is that your strong and vital immune system is successfully fighting off possible infections before you feel symptoms from them. Unless you are a literal hermit, you are exposed to infections all the time. Your immune system is working, not fading.

Comment: Maybe the idea is that someone with a very weak immune system might appear to "never have colds" because they get them, but don't mount much of an immune response to them, and most of the conspicuous symptoms of a cold *are* immune responses.  I'm not sure whether that's true, though.  Off-hand, it seems like if you caught a cold virus but couldn't mount the usual immune response to get rid of it you'd soon have much bigger and more obvious problems.  Maybe there is information about how this does play out in people with known immune deficiencies?